# PCI-DSS Compliance: SSL Tunneling Credit Card Information Through A HTTPS Mobile/Residential Proxy Service to A Destination Service

Tags: tls, pci-dss, credit-card, http-proxy, tunneling

If a PCI compliant service decides to SSL-Tunnel credit card information via an independent residential/mobile proxy service to a destination payment service, would this protocol still be PCI compliant?

Since the credit card information is Point-to-Point Encrypted, would this not still be PCI compliant? Does this open any new compliance issues? Or does this mean that the residential/mobile proxy service needs to be PCI-DSS compliant as well?

I would argue that the residential/mobile proxy does not need to be PCI-DSS compliant as the residential/mobile proxy service never received an unencrypted credit card data. Rather encrypted card data information was SSL tunneled through the residential/mobile proxy service. Is this argument valid?